# Error while building kivy app: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'typing_extensions'

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to package a Kivy app for android. This is the code that I'm trying to compile:

```
from pytube import YouTube

import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button


def download(url):

    try: 
        yt = YouTube(url)
        vids = yt.streams.order_by('resolution')

        #formVids = []

        if len(vids) > 0:

            print("Downloading...")
            vids.first().download()
            print("Video Downloaded")

        else:
            print("Couldn't download that video")

    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed to download video: ", e)


class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1

        self.inside = GridLayout()
        self.inside.cols = 2

        self.add_widget(Label(text="Note: Downloading Youtube videos is against Youtubes terms of service. \nDownload videos only if the creator is okay with it. E.g., a lot of gaming channels \nare okay with fans downloading content in order to make compilations. \nAlso not that downloading copyrighted content (songs, movies, etc) is a criminal offense.", halign = "center"))
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Paste the url of the video in the whitespace below"))
        self.name = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.name)

        self.submit = Button(text="Download", font_size=60)
        self.submit.bind(on_press=self.pressed)
        self.add_widget(self.submit)

    def pressed(self, instance):
        url = self.name.text
        download(url)
        print(url)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

And this is the full error:

```
Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
09-01 12:07:54.268 17974 18054 I python  : AND: Ran string
09-01 12:07:54.268 17974 18054 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
09-01 12:07:54.444 17974 18054 I python  : Traceback (most recent call last):
09-01 12:07:54.444 17974 18054 I python  :   File "/home/joshua/youtubeDownloader/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 1, in <module>
09-01 12:07:54.445 17974 18054 I python  :   File "/home/joshua/youtubeDownloader/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/youtubeDownloader/pytube/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
09-01 12:07:54.445 17974 18054 I python  :   File "/home/joshua/youtubeDownloader/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/youtubeDownloader/pytube/streams.py", line 22, in <module>
09-01 12:07:54.445 17974 18054 I python  :   File "/home/joshua/youtubeDownloader/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/youtubeDownloader/pytube/monostate.py", line 4, in <module>
09-01 12:07:54.445 17974 18054 I python  : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'typing_extensions'
09-01 12:07:54.445 17974 18054 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

I tried adding 'typing_extensions' into the buildozer.spec file next to the `requirements` specifier and that didn't work either. Any help for why this is happening and/or how to fix it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try reinstalling the typing_extensions package using:

```sh
pip uninstall typing_extensions 
pip install typing_extensions
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not really sure of my answer but,

Maybe You can try putting `typing-extensions` instead of `typing_extensions` in the `builder.spec` file.

replace `_` with `-` for that.

Comment: both names works with pip. but it might worth the try